# Converting date sequences to data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, date, sequence

I have a data frame with 9 observations of two different dates. Like:

```
df <- data.frame(date1 = c("2018-11-01", "2018-10-28", "2019-01-22", "2019-03-22", "2018-10-03", "2018-09-     10","2020-07-01", "2018-03-02", "2018-11-09"), 
                date2 = c("2018-12-31","2018-12-31","2018-12-31","2019-12-31","2018-12-31","2018-12-31","2020-12-31","2018-12-31","2018-12-31"))
```

For every pair of dates I want to extract the sequence between them by month and write it in a new data frame. For just one pair of observations I use: `seq(month(date1), month(date2))` 
This works nice but not so for date1 and date 2 being a vector > 1. I tried commands like rowwise or tried to loop through the original data frame but nothing worked out.

I tried:

```
df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  as.data.frame(df[i,])
```

or something like:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
   as.data.frame(df[i,])
  i = i + 1
   }
```

What I need is a single data frame for every sequence of months for every pair of dates like df1, df2, df3 ... and so on.
Every help or idea would be highly appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using `lubridate` and `dplyr`, here's a way using these and the (experimental) `group_split`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df |>
  mutate(across(everything(), ymd)) |>
  group_by(date1, date2) |>
  mutate(new = list(seq(month(date1), month(date2)))) |>
  unnest_longer(new) |>
  group_split(.keep = FALSE)
```

Output:

```r
[[1]]
# A tibble: 10 × 1
     new
   <int>
 1     3
 2     4
 3     5
 4     6
 5     7
 6     8
 7     9
 8    10
 9    11
10    12

[[2]]
# A tibble: 4 × 1
    new
  <int>
1     9
2    10
3    11
4    12

[[3]]
# A tibble: 3 × 1
    new
  <int>
1    10
2    11
3    12

[[4]]
# A tibble: 3 × 1
    new
  <int>
1    10
2    11
3    12

[[5]]
# A tibble: 2 × 1
    new
  <int>
1    11
2    12

[[6]]
# A tibble: 2 × 1
    new
  <int>
1    11
2    12

[[7]]
# A tibble: 12 × 1
     new
   <int>
 1     1
 2     2
 3     3
 4     4
 5     5
 6     6
 7     7
 8     8
 9     9
10    10
11    11
12    12

[[8]]
# A tibble: 10 × 1
     new
   <int>
 1     3
 2     4
 3     5
 4     6
 5     7
 6     8
 7     9
 8    10
 9    11
10    12

[[9]]
# A tibble: 6 × 1
    new
  <int>
1     7
2     8
3     9
4    10
5    11
6    12
```

---

**Update**: Although I would recommend keeping the data frames in a list, you could add them to the workspace using `list2env`:

```r
df |>
  mutate(across(everything(), ymd)) |>
  group_by(date1, date2) |>
  mutate(new = list(seq(month(date1), month(date2)))) |>
  unnest_longer(new) |>
  group_split(.keep = FALSE) -> listdf

names(listdf) <- paste0("monthdf", seq(length(listdf)))
list2env(listdf, .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: Hi, this is a very compact and safe way to do the job; never heard of group_split before. Is it possible to link up `as.data.frame` to the output?

Comment: You can add `|>  lapply(as.data.frame)` if you prefer data frames over tibbles.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I meant to save the 9 files into workspace.

Comment: See update using `list2env`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was working on this project now quite a while, my code is about 2000 lines. This was the last part missing. Now I can go and accomplish the task. Really, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through every row with `purrr::pmap`, instead of `rowwise`:

```
df %>%
  mutate(across(.fns = as.Date)) %>%
  pmap(~ as.Date(..1:..2))
```

This will return a list, because each sequence has different lengths. If they resulted in the same number of dates, then you could create a dataframe using `pmap_dfr` or `pmap_dfc`.

Result:

```
[[1]]
[1] "2018-11-01" "2018-11-02" "2018-11-03" "2018-11-04" "2018-11-05" ...

[[2]]
[1] "2018-10-28" "2018-10-29" "2018-10-30" "2018-10-31" "2018-11-01" ...

[[3]]
[1] "2019-01-22" "2019-01-21" "2019-01-20" "2019-01-19" "2019-01-18" ...

[[4]]
[1] "2019-03-22" "2019-03-23" "2019-03-24" "2019-03-25" "2019-03-26" ...

[[5]]
[1] "2018-10-03" "2018-10-04" "2018-10-05" "2018-10-06" "2018-10-07" ...

[[6]]
[1] "2018-09-10" "2018-09-11" "2018-09-12" "2018-09-13" "2018-09-14" ...

[[7]]
[1] "2020-07-01" "2020-07-02" "2020-07-03" "2020-07-04" "2020-07-05" ...

[[8]]
[1] "2018-03-02" "2018-03-03" "2018-03-04" "2018-03-05" "2018-03-06" ...

[[9]]
[1] "2018-11-09" "2018-11-10" "2018-11-11" "2018-11-12" "2018-11-13" ...
```